# Additive Properties of Definite Integrals

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $\int_a^bf(x)dx=I_1$ and $\int_a^bg(x)dx=I_2$ then prove that $$I_1+I_2=\int_a^b(f(x)+g(x))dx$$
$$$$Now as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both Integrable on $[a, b]$ so let us choose an arbitrary partition of $[a, b]$ with the width of $k^{th}$ sub interval equal to ${\Delta x}_k$. Now for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ there exists a ${\delta}_1>0$ such that whenever ${\Delta x}_{max}<{\delta}_1$ we have $$|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_k)\Delta x_k-I_1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ and also there exists a ${\delta}_2$ such that whenever ${∆x}_{max}<{\delta}_2$ we have $$|\sum_{k=1}^{n}g(c_k){\Delta x}_k-I_2|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$. Now if we chose $\delta=min({\delta}_1, {\delta}_2)$ then whenever ${\Delta x}_{max}<\delta$ both the above inequalities are satisfied. So we get $$\epsilon>|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_k)∆x_k-I_1|+|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_k){\Delta x}_k-I_2|>|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_k)\Delta x_k-I_1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(c_k){\Delta x}_k-I_2|=|\sum_{k=1}^{n}(f(c_k)+g(c_k)){\Delta x}_{k}-(I_1+I_2)|$$. So for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever ${∆x}_{max}<\delta$ we have $$|\sum_{k=1}^{n}(f(c_k)+g(c_k)){\Delta x}_{k}-(I_1+I_2)|<\epsilon$$. So we have $$\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_a^bg(x)dx=\int_a^b(f(x)+g(x))dx$$
$$$$Is My Proof Correct???

Comment: Pretty good, but you can't assume that the partitions are the same in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the proof should proceed like this. Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that whenever $\Delta x_{\text{max}}<\delta_1$, we have
 $$|\sum_i f(c_i)\Delta x_i|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
Similarly, there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that whenver $\Delta x_{\text{max}}<\delta_2$, we have 
$$|\sum_i g(c_i)\Delta x_i|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
Now take $\mathcal{P}$ to be a partition with $\Delta x_{\text{max}}<\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, then continue from here. In other words what I am saying is that you should assert the existence of the $\delta$ before choosing a partition.

Also I think it would be better to write "if we choose $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}\color{red}{>0}$".